# SCP from remote server to another remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have a server "B" which can SCP files to/from server "A" and can also SCP files to/from server "C".

i.e.
A <-----> B <-----> C

Server "A" and server "C" cannot reach each other. Only server B can reach both.
I would like to transfer a file from A to C without (or minimal) storage on server B.

Is there a way of piping files across from A to C without storing it in B or with minimal steps?

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic, but here you go: http://blog.sensible.io/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without scp if you like. Log into machine 'B' and run this:

```
ssh userA@A 'cat /source/file' | ssh userC@C 'cat > /dest/file'
```

You should set up one or both of these ssh instances to use a key for login, so that you're not prompted for passwords by two ssh instances at the same time.

If you want the file copy process to be a little more error-proofed, or if you want to transfer more than one file at a time, you can use `tar`:

```
ssh userA@A 'cd /source/dir && tar cf - file1 file2...' |
    ssh userC@C 'cd /dest/dir && tar xvf -'
```

If you'd rather run the command from A, then something like this should work:

```
tar cf - file... | ssh userB@B 'ssh userC@C "cd /dest/dir && tar xvf -" '
```

Answer (score 6):

From `scp(1)`:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> > ... Copies between two remote hosts
> >          are also permitted.

```
scp host1:foo.txt host2:foo.txt
```

Comment: Tried this but I think our servers have some configuration stopping it.

Comment: You may be running an older version that doesn't support it.

Comment: You should probably add the option `-3` to make the files pass through the local host. From the manual  "-3    Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data copied directly between the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the progress meter."

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a tunnel:

```
# Open a tunnel to server C
$ ssh -L 2222:<server C>:22 -N -l user <server B> & 
# Copy the file to server C
$ scp <file> -P 2222 localhost:<remote filename>
```

Note that the tunnel is still running after step 2.